# Register user on other website as signup on Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two sites A (custom PHP) and B (WordPress) running. Now I want to register user automatically as user signup on B (WordPress) sites. Can I do that? Means I want to fire event as user signup on WordPress site. Any hint or help.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If you run the two databases on the same server, you can probably use the Wordpress user table as your user table for site A.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Sorry i can't get you completely.i have two databases and different folder for websites.How can i use `user` table for `A` website ?

Comment: Can you modify site A so that it uses the Wordpress user table?

Comment: Yes in fact site `A` still don't have user table.How i modify so that it will use wordpress table ?

Comment: @halfer Sorry for the old question.As for that i didn't get any answer many days and i forgot that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the wordpress mysql database is available via a web url and you can give credentials to the custom php site (A) and you can connect..

example (from rackspace KB) http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely

Another example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70620/how-to-use-remote-db-tables-in-current-config